# save binary file after reading it using numpy

Tags: python, numpy

I have used the following code to parse a binary file using numpy. After reading the binary data, I want to save it to somewhere because I want to use this extracted data for another use/purpose. I am trying to use `np.save` but it is not saving anywhere. How do I save this data?

```
import numpy as np

with open(r'file_path', 'rb') as f:
    data = np.fromfile(f, dtype=np.int32, count=-1) 
    print (data)
    np.save(filenum,data)
```

Comment: did you check the `filenum` file in the home directory?

Comment: What is the value of `filenum`?  Is it a file object or file name?

Comment: Filenum is just a file name.

Comment: I have managed to resolve this issue. I used the following command to save the extracted data into the text file:                   
      np.savetxt('test.txt', data, delimiter=" ", fmt="%s")